# Fail to pass lat and lng API 0.5.4 Android

Tags: android, uber-api

I am using version 0.5.4 (Android) of api uber and passing the longitude and latitude data (destination and current location) but the information is not being displayed in the version v4.134.5 application. In version v3.134.5 it works normally.

What could be wrong?

```
        Double mapLat = Double.parseDouble(lat.toString());
        Double mapLng = Double.parseDouble(lng.toString());

        SessionConfiguration configuration = new SessionConfiguration.Builder()
                .setRedirectUri("https://www.example.com")
                .setClientId("CLIENT_ID")
                .setServerToken("SERVER_TOKEN")
                .build();

        validateConfiguration(configuration);
        ServerTokenSession session = new ServerTokenSession(configuration);

        RideParameters rideParametersForProduct = new RideParameters.Builder()
                //.setProductId(UBERX_PRODUCT_ID)
                .setPickupLocation(PICKUP_LAT, PICKUP_LONG, PICKUP_NICK, PICKUP_ADDR)
                .setDropoffLocation(mapLat, mapLng, razao_social, DROPOFF_ADDR)
                .build();

        // This button demonstrates deep-linking to the Uber app (default button behavior).
        blackButton = (RideRequestButton) findViewById(R.id.uber_ride);
        //blackButton.setRideParameters(rideParametersForProduct);
        blackButton.setSession(session);
        blackButton.setCallback(this);
        blackButton.loadRideInformation();
```

Comment: Can you explain in more details what happens when you open it? Do you have screenshots? Is it that the app does not deeplink or does the deeplink miss a property (e.g. nickname)?

Comment: The issue is likely that you are not passing in a product id. You need to pass a valid product id for the location when setting pickup/dropoff locations.